# SQL Server pre-deploy script to recreate table new columns and preserve data

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, database, visual-studio

I created a project in ASP.NET MVC with a separate database project which I run every time there is a table change. My only problem is that if I add one column for example, it will drop the entire database and recreate it and delete all data in the table.

Does anyone know of a pre-deployment script or a method I can use to add / remove / rename tables or column and at the same time preserve the integrity of my data? i.e keep my data while modifying my database

Comment: alter table Table_Name add Column_Name data_type {null | not null} . This will add the new column for you. NOT DROP YOUR DB, OR LOSS OF DATA.

Comment: This is a very generic question that is hard to respond without more context. Voted to close it as too broad.

Answer (score 0):

You can rename columns using SQL Server functions, but doing this risks breaking scripts used by other functions or stored procedures in your database. I don't endorse this practice, so I'm not posting about it below. Adding or removing columns is fair game.

You can add columns to a table by using the following query:

```
ALTER TABLE [YourTable]
ADD [ColumnName] [Datatype];
```

And you can drop columns using this query:

```
ALTER TABLE [YourTable]
DROP COLUMN [ColumnName];
```

These SQL commands will preserve the other columns in your table. If you want to change a column name I encourage you to set up a View in your SQL Server client and give the column an alias.

This can be accomplished using:

```
CREATE VIEW [ViewName]
AS
SELECT [ColumnName] AS [ColumnAlias]
FROM [TableName]
GO
```

You'd be able to perform SELECTS on the view in just the same way you can query SELECT on a normal table, except you can query the `[ColumnAlias]` instead of the `[ColumnName]`. You cannot perform INSERT or DELETE queries on a view, however